# How to segregate a linked list into two other lists, one with odd indices the other one with even indices but in recursion way

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

The question asked to write a function that can split a linked list into two other lists, one with odd indices the other one with even indices but recursively . I have read all the similar questions in stack overflow ,  but they did not have recursive way .

Here is my try:

```
public class LinkedList {
Node head;
static int count = 0;
static LinkedList oddList = new LinkedList();
static LinkedList evenList = new LinkedList();

static class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

public static void split(Node head) {

    if (head == null) return;
    split(head.next);
    if ((++count) % 2 == 0) {
        insert(evenList, head.data);
    } else
        insert(oddList, head.data);
}
```

This program just do the **traverse** recursively not the inserting , I do  not know how to traverse and insert elements in my two linked list **all in recursion** .

Could you help me write that function to do that work .?

Comment: What about an instance method that removes every second object in the list and add it to another list recursively, so remove odd indices and keep the even? It looks odd that you add a bunch of static variables to your class just so you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
TwoLists splitEvenAndOddIndices(List originalList) {
    if (originalList.isEmpty()) {
        return two empty lists;
    }
    Element head = remove the head (the frontmost element) from originalList;
    TwoLists result = splitEvenAndOddIndices(originalList);
    Swap the two lists in result;
    Prepend head to the first list in result,
    return result;
}
```